# react await async calling too soon giving undefined then the right result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, use-effect

I'm using `async` and `await`, however the result it calling two sets of times, the first set returns the empty default from the `useEffect`, and then 2nd time returns the correct data from the call.

This is leading to the data not rendering in the component.

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useEasybase } from 'easybase-react';

export default function Data() {

    const [easybaseData, setEasybaseData] = useState([]);

    const { db } = useEasybase();

    const mounted = async() => {
        const ebData = await db("cars").return().limit(1).all();
        setEasybaseData(ebData);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        mounted();
    }, []);    

    console.log('easybaseData');

    const ez = easybaseData[0]; 

    const i = ez?.image;
    const n = ez?.name;
    const p = ez?.price;

    console.log(i);

    return (
        <Grid item xs={6} id={"outputs-grid"}>
            <div className="image-result-wrapper">
                <img
                    src={`http://localhost:3000/assets/images/${i}`}
                    className="image-result"
                />
                </div>
                <div className="details-result-wrapper">
                <p className="details-result">{n}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="price-result-wrapper">
                <p className="price-result">{`Evaluation: $${p}`}</p>
            </div>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

and the console.log:

[image]

What am I missing about this?  All 3 data for image, name and price are returning undefined in inspector.

[image]

Comment: Use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to log the state after it's changed `useEffect(() => console.log(easybaseData), [easybaseData]);`

Comment: *All 3 data for image, name and price are returning undefined in inspector.* -- `easybaseData` appears to be an array of objects, not a single object. So doing `easybaseData.image` will always truly be undefined. Instead, you'll need to access the correct object by index (like `easybaseData[0].image`)

Comment: Andy I tried that and it did the same except now only one empty array and one of the actual result arrays are logged. 
@BrianThompson That is a good point Brian.  I changed it to call the first array elem, but in the first case it's still showing undefined because it's basically just the origin empty list from the useEffect I think (ie. it hasn't pulled any data yet)

Comment: @DanielSon That is expected. `useEffect` runs **after** the render. So there will always be at least one render with you initial data (an empty array). That's just how it works. You'll need to plan for it by checking against empty data, conditional rendering, or some other strategy.

Comment: I updated the code two with the full page in case it helps

Comment: My last comment is still the answer. What you're seeing is exactly how it is designed to work. You async code is irrelevant to the timing of the console logs, because the async function isn't even called until after the first log with empty data has been fired.

Comment: It's not solving it though - all its done is this (https://ibb.co/60xBByw) and for the log itself now removed the two calls that showed the right results (https://ibb.co/J5vPDXD)

Comment: Yes, because like I said - *You'll need to plan for it by checking against empty data, conditional rendering, or some other strategy*. You have an empty array on the first render. So of course, that array does not hold an object at index 0. Attempting to do `[][0].image` will break, because index 0 is undefined. You need to *plan* for this case that is guaranteed to happen by making sure the array is filled first.

Comment: Depending on you browser compatibility requirements and transpiling situation, you could do something as simple as `const i = ez?.image;`. Or you could wrap the whole thing in a check against the array length. The strategy is up to you, it just has to be accounted for in some way.

Comment: I added the modification you mentioned.. making ez conditional (I think that's what you were saying to do).  And also added another image at the bottom with the result of doing that.  Now I'm getting undefined twice and null twice.  If that's not what you meant, can you provide a direct description of what I should try and I'll try that instead.

Comment: Following @BrianThompson comments, and @Andy all you need to do is check if `easybaseData.length>0` if so render the Grid if not render something like 'Loading Data' or render a spinner, you get the point. You need to account for the event when the data is not available

Comment: Your question is still missing some important data, making my comments general advice and facts about react, but not an answer. To get a true answer, you'll need to include *exactly* the structure of the data returned from your async function.